# Excel - Return a (comma seperated), list of values paired to a second value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In the situation whereby I have data like below:

```
A   22-Aug-14
B   22-Aug-14
C   22-Aug-14
D   22-Aug-14
E   22-Aug-14
F   22-Aug-14
G   22-Aug-14
A   23-Aug-14
B   23-Aug-14
A   24-Aug-14
B   26-Aug-14
```

How can I return a format similar to:

```
22-Aug-14   A,B,C,D,E,F,G
23-Aug-14   A,B
24-Aug-14   A
26-Aug-14   B
```

Where the values in the first column have been paired to the values in the 2nd and displayed in a list form seperated by commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution which use excel formulas only (Not the solution by Macro program).

I assumed followings for making the code below.

1) Values are placed in A column, 2) Dates are placed in B column and they are sorted, 3) Data are exists from 1st row to 100th row.

Do following Steps:

1. put formula "=A1" to cell C1.
2. put formula "=if(B1=B2,C1&A1,A1)" to cell C2.
3. copy cell C2, then paste to C3 to C100.
4. put formula "=B1<>B2" to cell D1.
5. copy cell D1, then paste to cell D2 to D100.
6. copy cells C1 to D100, then paste_as_value to same place.
7. select rows whose D column is TRUE.
8. Column B and C will be what you expected.

Comment: Great! I got 1/3 of the way through the data using a VBA function I made, but was part manual, this did the job perfectly. Thanks